# Alter cube dimension by using XMLA

Tags: ssas, olap, olap-cube, xmla

By using XMLA how to access WriteEnabled dimension property and modify it?
Here is a sample I'm using for that

```
<Alter ObjectExpansion="ExpandFull" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
    <Object>
        <DatabaseID>DB</DatabaseID>
        <DimensionID>My dimension</DimensionID>
    </Object>
    <ObjectDefinition>
        <Dimension xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"               xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2"
                   xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2"               xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100">
            <WriteEnabled>false</WriteEnabled>
            <ID>My dimension</ID>
            <Name>Dimension name</Name>
            <Attributes>
                <Attribute>
                    <Name>Attribute name/Name>
                </Attribute>
            </Attributes>
        </Dimension>
    </ObjectDefinition>
</Alter>
```

Running this script I'm getting following error: Errors in the metadata manager. The 'My dimension' dimension has either zero or multiple key attributes.

What is missing in a script above?

Answer (score 1):

Seems the key columns node and Name columns nodes for your attribute have missing: 
Here is an example for a dim attributes node, hope it helps:

[image: attribute node example]

You can create a cube manually, and then check the alter script by right click the cube name for a reference also.